# MethodError: undefined method `sign_in' for RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, railstutorial.org

In the Chapter 9 of the Ruby on Rails tutorial of Michael Hartl i am facing a problem with RSpec tests as they don't see my sign_in method defined in the file utilities.rb. I am stuck, I have checked everything and it seems correct. I saw similar posts where the line include ApplicationHelper helped to somebody, but I already have it, and also I have no problems with the method "full_title" which is laced in the same file.

```
utilities.rb:

def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  if page_title.empty?
    base_title
  else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
  end
end

def sign_in(user, options={})
  if options[:no_capybara]
    #Sign in when not using Capybara
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    else
      visit signin_path
      fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
      fill_in "Password", with: user.password
      click_button "Sign in"
  end
end
```

and the failed file user_pages_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'
include ApplicationHelper
...
...
...
describe "edit" do
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before do 
  sign_in user
  visit edit_user_path(user)
end

describe "page" do
  it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
  it { should have_title("Edit user") }
  it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
end
...
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're having a hard time including that method, you can try including it directly on your spec.

```
require 'rails_helper'
...
describe "page" do
  it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
  it { should have_title("Edit user") }
  it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
end 
....


private

def sign_in(user, options={})
  if options[:no_capybara]
    #Sign in when not using Capybara
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    else
      visit signin_path
      fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
      fill_in "Password", with: user.password
      click_button "Sign in"
  end
```

If that works, go ahead and make a new module with helper methods for your specs, then include that in your spec_helper / rails_helper

Comment: Thank you! it worked, so, I put it back into the file support/utilities.rb and added a route to this file in the rails_helper.rb: require 'support/utilities'
 and now all tests are green! =)